# Chrome's input cursor goes wrong

Tags: html, google-chrome

as you can see the input cursor goes very end in the fifth line, this situation appears a long time and I use edge to do some coding recently, this situation only appears in chrome.

[image]

I didn't want to reinstall chrome, are there any useful tricks?

Comment: My guess is you have spaces or tabs at the end of that line.  Get rid of those, and the behavior will stop.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is very light on information that users could employ to assist you. Currently I don't think you're likely to get many responses. Please consider checking out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updating your question accordingly. Good luck!